# Sortable/draggable list items without jQuery UI (or jQuery at all?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, zepto

I've been looking for a Javascript plugin that would provide the same basic functionnality as [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/). Wich is dragging and dropping items for reordering them. In my case those items are `<li>` tags.

Basically, I don't want to use jQuery UI because it's quite heavy and, as I don't need to support IE, I'm using Zepto instead of jQuery. So I don't want to load jQuery AND jQuery UI just for this. That being said, I could easily live with a working jQuery plugin and adapt it so it works with Zepto.

I've been looking for this for quite some time but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Heavy how? Core + mouse + widget +dragable + sortable = 53k 
The support which is available for the UI would alone make it worth it.

Comment: The thing is, as I've said, I am not using jQuery at all in this project. So the accurate math would be jQuery + UI Core + Mouse + Widget + Draggable = ~85k. It's a lot for something that's not crucial .

Answer (score 2):

Whilst this doesn't have the full functionaility as jQuery UI Sortable you might be able to use this Zepto - Drag and Drop plugin.

https://github.com/netotaku/zepto-drag-and-drop.js